# android achartengine not zooming

Tags: android, zooming, achartengine

I'm using the AChartEngine, but for some reason it's not zooming by pinch, only by buttons, here is the code:

```
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset;
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer;
    private GraphicalView mChartView;
    private TimeSeries time_series;

mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(3f);
        mRenderer.setZoomRate(0.5f);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);

        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        r.setFillPoints(true);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(20);
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);

        time_series = new TimeSeries("test");

        mDataset.addSeries(time_series);

        fillData();

        mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer,
                "yyyy-MM-dd");

        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart)).addView(mChartView);


private void fillData() {
        long value = new Date().getTime() - 3 * TimeChart.DAY;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            time_series.add(new Date(value + i * TimeChart.DAY / 4), i);
        }
    }
```

and here is the xml part:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:
Also it's not moving at all**

for the library I'm using the `achartengine-1.1.0.jar`
can anyone see what I'm doing wrong ?

thank you

Comment: Try after remove `mRenderer.setZoomRate(0.5f);` this line. Let me know what happened.

Comment: thanks, but still not working

Comment: Also replace setZoomEnabled(true) with setZoomEnabled(true, true)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have found the answer by now. But here's the solution to people who have at the same problem.

Add a click listener to your `GraphicalView`.
In this case --

```
mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good hack. For some reason, a ClickListener, even with out any code inside gets the pan and zoom working. With out it, the chart is static.

Here is the code...

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mChartView == null) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container_layout);
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataset, renderer);
            mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
            layout.addView(mChartView);

        } else {
            mChartView.repaint();
        }
    }
```